# Serializing a C# class into a complex JSON

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I have been working on an application for a legacy project. This application uses OAuth for user authentication.

For this purpose, the application builds a JSON and then adds this to a request sent to the authentication server. This JSON looks like this:

[image: Source]

My application generates this JSON at each authentication attempt by serializing 2 separate C# classes to simulate the structures seen here.

I do this to avoid complications with special characters inside the user name or the password. Assuming of course my plan works.

In addition, since all of this is legacy, I'm no longer allowed to add or upgrade any packages, which tends to limit my options, given the age (15+ years) of the codebase.

The 1st class is **UserPasswordJson**:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;

namespace JsonSerialization.Json
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;

    [DataContract]
    public class UserPasswordJson
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "scope", IsRequired = true, Order = 1)]
        public List<string> Scope { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "data", IsRequired = true, Order = 2)]
        public string Data { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "profile_id", IsRequired = true, Order = 3)]
        public string ProfileId { get; set; }
        

        public UserPasswordJson(string userName, string password)
        {
            Scope = new List<string> { "SomeCompany" };

            var randomGenerator = new Random();

            var randomNumber = randomGenerator.Next(999999);
            ProfileId = randomNumber.ToString("D6");

            var userPassword = new UserPasswordCombination(userName, password);
            var stream = new MemoryStream();
            var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(UserPasswordCombination));
            serializer.WriteObject(stream, userPassword);

            stream.Position = 0;
            var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream);

            var jsonString = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

            Data = jsonString;
        }
    }
}
```

The 2nd class is **UserPasswordCombination**:

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace JsonSerialization.Json
{
    [DataContract]
    public class UserPasswordCombination
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "username", IsRequired = true, Order = 1)]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "password", IsRequired = true, Order = 2)]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        public UserPasswordCombination(string userName, string password)
        {
            UserName = userName;
            Password = password;
        }
    }
}
```

So, whenever I want to serialize the objects I do:

```
public static string BuildJson(string userName, string password)
{
    var jsonObject = new UserPasswordJson(userName, password);

    var stream = new MemoryStream();
    var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(UserPasswordJson));
    serializer.WriteObject(stream, jsonObject);

    stream.Position = 0;
    var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream);
    var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

    return result;
}
```

I've been playing around with this in a console application, to easily check the JSON file it generates. So far I've done 3 separate tests:

1. **No special characters**

[image: json_1]

2. **1 special character**

[image: json_2]

3. **A bunch of special characters**

[image: json_3]

Each JSON file is valid, but I'm not sure they will deserialize properly. I have no idea how the other side will deal with these files, so I'm trying to double-check things.

Anyone here has an idea of whether or not I'm still missing something, or if the idea I had will actually do what I intend it to do?

Comment: It probably will not deserialize properly. You need to put `data` in as an `object` not a `string`, and don't double serialize

Comment: That was just one of the things here. The json that was sent to the authentication server contained a json object as a string. Strange, I know. The only workaround I found for that  was the double serialization.

Comment: Then if that's what you need then it will deserialize fine. The escaping of special characters is supposed to be there. You just need to take that deserialized string and deserialize it again.